# OnGestureListener#onScroll not being called from GestureDetector on Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1

Tags: android, scroll, gesturedetector

On a Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 with Android 4.0.4 the `GestureDetector` does not fire `OnGestureListener#onScroll` when two fingers are placed on screen (it does for one finger). This works well on other devices. In my application I want to enable scrolling only when at least two fingers are involved.

This is the view implementation to reproduce the phenomena:

```
public class MyView extends View {

    GestureDetector scrollGestureDetector;

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        scrollGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onScroll(final MotionEvent e1, final MotionEvent e2, final float distanceX, final float distanceY) {
                System.out.println("SCROLL " + distanceX + ", " + distanceY);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        scrollGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Is this behavior known/documented/wanted? Are there known workarounds?

Comment: try `return false;` @ `onTouchEvent`

Comment: Returning false signals that MyView is not interested in/has not consumed the event. This disables scrolling completely. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)

Comment: Filed as bug report: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63129&thanks=63129&ts=1386001753

Comment: This seems to be a general problem for some Android SDKs. At least in Android 4.4 the GestureDetector is able to handle two-finger-scrolling.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to implement one more method `onDown` in your `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener`, like this:

```
scrollGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(final MotionEvent e1, final MotionEvent e2, final float distanceX, final float distanceY) {
            System.out.println("SCROLL " + distanceX + ", " + distanceY);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

    });
```

Because according to [this document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html#onDown(android.view.MotionEvent)) and [this guide](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html#detect):

> Notified when a tap occurs with the down MotionEvent that triggered
>   it. This will be triggered immediately for every down event. All other
>   events should be preceded by this.

And

> Whether or not you use GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, it's best
>   practice to implement an onDown() method that returns true. This is
>   because all gestures begin with an onDown() message. If you return
>   false from onDown(), as GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener does
>   by default, the system assumes that you want to ignore the rest of the
>   gesture, and the other methods of GestureDetector.OnGestureListener
>   never get called. This has the potential to cause unexpected problems
>   in your app. The only time you should return false from onDown() is if
>   you truly want to ignore an entire gesture.

You need to `return true` in `onDown`, so that `onScroll` will be triggered.

Comment: YOU... saved me so much time. And so, I lost so much already... Please note that this does not occurs ONLY on that specific device. What brought me here is that double tap disable "onscroll"... And this answer solved it.